# p5js website infinite page

Tags: html, processing, p5.js

hello i have a question i cant answer and need it to finish or even start my website.

i am able to create a canvas with p5js style it with css and then load a website with html.index..

i would like to know how to create a page that is endless,for example if i scroll right 5mins it scrolls and vice versa left up down....

a lot like this website here...

// uses flash///

http://www.bio-bak.nl/

i basically want to create a world or large page similar to above link or even similar to google maps.....

a page that can endless scroll in all directions using html,p5js,js or whatever possible.

i asked someone before and they possible using this idea

```
if Pos > height - ~10% height =height + 100px//do same for right,left,up,down.
```

maybe using `document.body.scrollTop` ?

the problems i have come across is i create canvas with p5js and i can position the canvas but i don't know how to position page below the canvas that the canvas is lying on?

hopefully by looking at the website above you maybe can understand what i want.

a problem i have found so far in my code is i always arrive the top left of page i imagine this is x,y 0,0 possible..but i want my canvas to appear middle of page so when i arrive on website i can scroll up left right anyway but at the moment if i refresh website and arrive on page i can only scroll right or down i am not able to scroll all directions because i am already at pos 0,0 of x,y from what i believe...

please if someone can got ideas would love some help as its the only thing i need to continue construction of my website...

really what i want is exactly like website posted above i want to scroll or drag a long way in all directions the same as in a platform game i continuously walk in one direction ?

thanks in advance first post ever here and new to coding since few months...

enjoy

Comment: Hi! In order for us to help you, you should try to be more concise, and provide an [mcve](/help/mcve). Also, did you check the [tour](/tour)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a big ambition, so I'm not going to provide a total solution but rather some ideas to get you started.

First use [`Window.innerWidth`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp) to get the size of the window and set your canvas that large. Now, you have a fullscreen canvas. To detect when the user scrolls use [`mouseWheel()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseWheel). This should be everything you need to create a fake "endless scroll" through p5.js.

Now use [`translate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) to move items where you want, making sure to offset their position by the `mouseWheel()` input you've gathered. This should create the illusion of infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You really have two questions:

**Question One:** How do I draw an infinite page?

There are a ton of ways to do this. You could use procedural generation, or constantly load new data, or you could "teleport" items to the bottom when they go off the top, or maybe you don't really mean infinite and you can just draw stuff that goes off the screen.

You haven't really said how you're doing this, but I think you're mostly asking about the second question:

**Question Two:** How do I change my view of an infinite page?

There are also a ton of ways to do this. One of the simplest ways to think about this is to just draw your scene (it's okay if a lot of it is drawn off the screen at the beginning), but for every coordinate to have an **offset** that you change in order to change where the "camera" is. Something like this:

```
var offsetX = 0;

function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function mouseDragged(){
    offsetX += (mouseX - pmouseX)/2;
}

function draw() { 
  background(220);
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        ellipse(-10000 + i*100 + offsetX, height/2, 100, 100);  
    }
}
```

Link to runnable code: [here](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/KevinWorkman/sketches/rybQHjfHb).

You could also use something like the `translate()` function to move the camera instead of using an offset.

Comment: this is good thanks it`s got me allot further thanks, can you explain one thing  ellipse(-10000 + i*100 + offsetX, offsetY, 100, 100); this works for both directions.but what does -10000 + etc. do ?

Comment: this is good thanks it`s got me allot further thanks, can you explain one thing  ellipse(-10000 + i*100 + offsetX, offsetY, 100, 100); this works for both directions.but what does -10000 + i*100 etc. do ? is it still the same as ellipse(x,y,w,[h])?what do the [h] do around h aswell?whats the difrence between page and canvas?as in when i choose a small canvas and open it in firefox it shows a small canvas in corner rather than changing the size of the firfox tab?

Comment: if i wanted to use (mouseX - pmouseX) but instead of one elipse i would want to do it with a hole bunch of things,imgs,gifs,<p/>and stuff,how can i round them into one varable ?

Comment: @jennydarbs The `for` loop is just an example that draws a bunch of circles. It starts at `-10000`, which is very far off the left edge of the screen, and then draws `1000` circles that are each `100` pixels wide. This is just simulating an "infinite" scene to show the scrolling part of it. The difference between a page and a canvas is that a canvas is an element in a page.